# Replace string in php which uses $ without referencing a variable

Tags: php

I worded the title very badly, but you'll understand what I mean.

Here's a piece of code:

```
$value = $row['value'];
$fieldValue = str_replace("$value", $value, $existsValue);
```

I want to replace all instances of the literal "$value" within a string with the value of the variable $value.

So for example the string might be "Hello, my name is $value."

So I want to replace $value with the real value that is stored in the variable.

Comment: change quotes to single `str_replace('$value',..`

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332

Comment: @splash58 Ah, thank you. I'm stupid.

Comment: You want to replace $value with the value stored in $value? So just use it as a variable and it will?